# QT4 to QT5 networking issue - UDP

Tags: c++, qt, udp, migration

I'm pretty new to Qt.  I inherited a QtCreator project built using Qt 4.8.1 and have been attempting to rebuild it with Qt 5.4.2 to add functionality.  I have successfully rebuilt the project under windows 7 (Mingw) and linux with Qt5.

Everything works well until I start the connected devices and receive the UDP stream - where the old project (on the same machine as new code) will happily receive and store data, the new project chokes very quickly at some arbitrary amount of data and will not accept new data.

**EDIT** packet size - all incoming small packets are received.  There is typically some control and ack packets of small size ( ~100 bytes ) that work fine.  The problem is once data acquisition starts; the incoming data packet payload is 1441 bytes and this will choke rapidly.

```
#include <QThread>
#include <QUdpSocket>
#ifdef linux
#include <sys/socket.h>
#elif _WIN32
#include <winsock2.h>
#else
#error Platform not supported
#end

// etc

void ReceiveSocket::run()
{
    udpReceiveSocket = new QUdpSocket();
    connect( udpReceiveSocket, SIGNAL( readyRead() ), this, SLOT( readPendingDatagrams() ) );
    udpReceiveSocket->moveToThread( this );
    exec();
}

// etc

void ReceiveSocket::readPendingDatagrams()
{
    QByteArray * data;
    while( udpReceiveSocket->hasPendingDatagrams() ) {
        data = new QByteArray;
        data->resize( udpReceiveSocket->pendingDatagramSize() );
        QHostAddress sender;
        quint16 senderPort;
        udpReceiveSocket->readDatagram( data->data(),
                sdata->size(),&sender, &senderPort );
        emit processDatagrams( data );
    }
}
```

Has anyone experience this issue migrating to Qt5?  Is there an obvious cause to an arbitrary stoppage?  I have added a debug counter in the processDatagrams method to show the running count of datagrams processed and it varies but is around a few hundred before it quits.

**EDIT** I added a counter to the while loop and printed using qDebug.  This would obviously slow things down and the data does acquire at about 1/10th the actual data rate and it will continue indefinitely.  This may hint at the problem.

```
void ReceiveSocket::readPendingDatagrams()
{
    volatile int i = 0;
    QByteArray * data;
    while( udpReceiveSocket->hasPendingDatagrams() ) {
        qDebug()<<i;
        i++;
        data = new QByteArray;
        data->resize( udpReceiveSocket->pendingDatagramSize() );
        QHostAddress sender;
        quint16 senderPort;
        udpReceiveSocket->readDatagram( data->data(),
                sdata->size(),&sender, &senderPort );
        emit processDatagrams( data );
    }
}
```

For now, I'm going to use Qt4 libraries until I have a better opportunity to debug behavior with Qt5

Comment: You never initialize `QByteArray *data`, yet you try to use it. Why don't you just declare it as `QByteArray data;`? Also why do you have two `QByteArray`s?

Comment: I edited sdata out - typo

Comment: Is there a reason `data` is a pointer? Do you even delete it anywhere?

Comment: I assume `data` is a pointer for the signal/slot connection.  I've never used signals and slots before.  `data` is deleted in the slot - this concerns me but `delete( data )` is called in `processDatagrams`.  Can I delete `data` after the emit statement (the signal/slot blocks?)?  This seems safer.

Comment: I don't think you should even bother with using a pointer. Just make it an automatic variable, and if it is a direct connection (i.e. the slot is in the same thread as the thread that emits the signal) you could just pass a const reference. That way you won't have to worry about deleting anything and your variable won't be copied.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, no need for `new QByteArray`

```
void ReceiveSocket::readPendingDatagrams()
{
    while( udpReceiveSocket->hasPendingDatagrams() ) {
        int len = udpReceiveSocket->pendingDatagramSize();
        QByteArray data;
        data->resize(len);
        udpReceiveSocket->readDatagram(data.data());
        emit processDatagrams( data );
    }
}
```

so this should fix a possible error with `data` (not initialized)`and`sdata`(whatever this is). I discarded the variables`sender`and`senderPort` because they were not needed in your code and you can add them if needed later

Note that UDP datagrams are kind of restricted in size. they will get split up at a certain length by the socket itself when it is longer than the packet size. I usually use packets with size of <512, should be the minimum default length of UDP data packets by routers and such

Comment: sdata was a typo - this code worked in the Qt4 implementation but not in Qt5.  I am concerned about packet size.  I do not have control over the incoming packet size ( the problem UDP payload size is 1441, other smaller datagrams are delivered ).  The network consists of two devices, a switch, and the computer.  I can verify the devices are working and all packets are delivered using Wireshark.  I will edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

This bug appeared in Qt 5.4.2. Either downgrade to 5.4.1 or enclose the event handling code in a loop as suggested by Zaiborg.

Comment: Egnite - do you have a Qt bug report number I could refer to?

Comment: I intended to add a bug report today, but a quick search showed, that one exists already, even a related fix, see QTBUG-43857.